# Transactions in Doobie for Scala / Play Framework

Tags: scala, functional-programming, psql, scala-cats, doobie

I have a question regarding transactions in doobie.
I have looked over the documentation here and it looks like it can only handle one query at a time?

Is it possible to have something like this

```
sql'''
begin;
select * from table where id=1 for update;
update table set id=2 where tabletest=2;
commit'''
```

any ideas or more examples/documentations anyone can point me to will be much appreciated! thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You are running things in transaction when you apply the `Transactor`

```
query.transact(transactor)
```

but that doesn't mean that you have to run whole transaction in a single line:

```
val operations = for {
  myClass <- sql"""SELECT a, b, c, FROM table_x WHERE ...""".query[MyClass].to[List]
  updatedRows <- sql"""UPDATE table_x SET ... WHERE""".update.run
} yield someResult

operations.transact(transctor)
```

Basically you turn each query/update into `ConnectionIO` which is a monad - you can use all monadic/applicative/functor operations from Cats there - `flatMap`, `map`, `mapN`, `tupled`, etc - to combine these `ConnectionIO`s into bigger `ConnectionIO`s and once you are done run them (you have been building queries but haven't been executing them so far!) with `.transact(transactor)` into the actual result computed in a transaction. `BEGIN-COMMIT-or-ROLLBACK` is handled by that `.transact(transactor)` which is why you don't write it yourself.

See [Doobie documentation](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/) with this [FAQ](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/17-FAQ.html) (*How do I do several things in the same transaction?*) in particular.